# Размер div по количеству вложенных в него div-ов

Tags: html, javascript

Имеется некий Div class="main" (предварительно в нем находятся превью товаров, каждый товар в отдельном div). Есть желание, чтоб ширина main-а варьировалась в зависимости от количества вложенных в него div-вов. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сие реализовать на Js?

Comment: То есть, если ширина внутренних div-вов = 200px, и их допустим 4, то общая ширина 800px => ширина main = 800px, если их (div-вов) - 20, то => div class="main" style="width:4000px"

Comment: display: inline-block; в СSS

Comment: Само собой, только когда блоки дойдут до края экрана, они будут переноситься на новую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы внутренние блоки выстроились горизонтально:

```
.item { display: inline-block; }
```

Чтобы не было переносов:

```
.main { white-space: nowrap; }
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hgt4L/)

Comment: Оказалось гораздо проще! Спасибо